# Lookup a value in Excel, and if not found, round down to the nearest value?

Tags: excel

I have a list of values, say:

```
100 a
250 b
430 c
775 d
1250 e
```

On another sheet, I have a row with a value on it, say

```
asdf 1225
asdh 1250
```

So I want to construct a formula which is like vlookup, but for the 1st row with value 1225 instead of returning `#N/A` I want it to return the closest value rounded down - in this case the value mapped to '775' or 'd'. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard `VLOOKUP` will do this, providing it is an option (i.e. a rounded-down value exists). The key is not to specify the optional `range_lookup` argument or set it to `TRUE` or `1`(the default). Bear in mind this only works with sorted data.

[image: vlookup arguments]

Whenever I use a `VLOOKUP`, I explicitly set to `FALSE` so that only exact matches are returned.

If you could end up with a value that is smalleer than you your smallest value in the list (i.e. smaller than 100 from the above), use an `IFNA` to specify what value should be used in that scenario:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(),"does this when vlookup returns N/A)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I always wondered what the ambigious match was to be honest, do you know? It just seem to match to random things for me.